# Fetch API slow in react-native@0.55 release build

Tags: react-native, fetch, ipod

I use `fetch` in my react-native app for API calls.
This works fine in development builds, but slows down to several *seconds* in a release build.

The problem is not with the API; a request takes about 100~300 ms to complete (according to the ngrok inspector). This is true for both dev and release builds.

When I log the time before and after the `fetch`, there's a delay that I can't explain.

The simplest use case (even in a fresh react-native@0.56 app) slows down to a crawl when I do a API call in a release build.

```
console.log('start request');
const response = await fetch('http://...');
console.log('request completed');
```

The time between these logs varies between several 100ths of ms up to 6, 7 seconds (the non-async/await approach suffers the same sluggishness).

The response is always `application/json`, and I unpack it using the `response.json()` function. But even with a response such as `{"test": 123}`, it's still slow.

I can imagine having done something wrong during the react-native upgrade process, but what I don't understand is why this happens even in a completely boilerplate new react-native app.

All our tests indicate that iPods (6th gen) suffer this problem, not recent iPhones. Has anyone else encountered (and hopefully been able to fix) this?

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: This happens on Android only in my side, and its fast on debug mode. any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Check with `xmlhttprequest` or use the `axios` instead of fetch api. And also check the time taken for this request in curl

In the terminal: `curl -s -w 'Total: %{time_total}s\n' 'https://examplerequest.com'`. So you can find what happen?